# Declare variable type as abstract class pops error when I set that variable with a value that implements the abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class

I have an abstract class

```
abstract class Animal {}
```

And then I have a class that implements it:

```
class Cow extends Animal {}
```

And finally I want to type a variable with the abstract class type and set to the variable a class that implements the abstract class:

```
let animal1: Animal = Cow;
```

But typescript says that they are not the same class. Do you have any idea of how to solve this situation?

Comment: You forgot `new`. `Cow` is the `Cow` class, `new` it to create an `Animal`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't need an instance of the class, I just need the class itself to generate a component dynamically using compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync of Angular.

Comment: Then you need `let animal1: typeof Animal = Cow;` That declares a variable having the type of a constructor function that creates `Animal` instances when called with `new`.

Comment: Yeah that worked! Thanks Aluan!

Comment: Try this too: `let animal1: <Animal> = Cow;`